Django 4.2: Apply sorting Child Table key based on foreignkey
please see below model definition
class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        prduct_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

class ProductRateInfo(models.Model):
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rate_info')
    season_start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    season_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sbr_rate = models.FloatField(default=0)

While fetching the product we need apply sorting ProductRateInfo.sbr_rate column
Tried below method but it's not working
product_qs = Product.object.fitler(prduct_type='demotest').prefetch_related('rate_info')


There's an error in your code
product_qs = Product.object.fitler(prduct_type='demotest').prefetch_related('rate_info')

You used fitler instead of filter.
The correct code should look like this:
product_qs = Product.object.filter(prduct_type='demotest').prefetch_related('rate_info')

See also Interaction with prefetching on Django docs for more.
